# Why Picker not filled with data from json web api - Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I trying to fill a picker with json data from web api

```
 <Picker x:Name="picker"
        Title="Изберете станция"
        TitleColor="Black">
        </Picker>
```

In c# file:

```
public async Task FillStation_HQ_AHSAsync()
    {
        var result = await _restServiceStations.Get_HQ_AHS(Constants.EndPoint);

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var stationsList = new List<string>();
            stationsList.Add(item.ToString());
            picker.ItemsSource = stationsList;
        }
    }
```

So result have more than 200 items with two properties: "Station" and "Ime".. but when I click on the picker he is empty..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the logic for building your list is bad

```
var stationsList = new List<string>();  

foreach (var item in result)
{
    stationsList.Add(item.ToString());
}

picker.ItemsSource = stationsList;
```